# How to suppress all default variables and default implicit rules in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to start with a clean-slate Makefile, so every implicit rule should be explicitly declared, without any surprises.

I want to suppress also all default variables and suffix rules.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `make -rR`

Or adding to Makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR
```

**NOTE:** It seems that on older version of Gnu-Make (prior to version 4.0), You should also add:

```
.SUFFIXES :
```

[GNU-Make Maintainer](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?20501#comment8):

> "That's why in the makefile you need BOTH the .SUFFIXES: special target AND the MAKEFLAGS+=-r.  Having the .SUFFIXES: special target set to empty ensures that no suffix rules are searched but it does NOT remove all the suffix rules from the database.  So they still show up with -p, but they don't have any impact on the algorithms make uses to build targets".